# Searching a specific string in a file and save the string coming after in a file in python

Tags: python, string, search

I want to save some speicific data from files I have, it looks like something like that :

```
[StagePositionMapFile]
[StageMapPosition]
XCoordinate=-1.37525e-003
YCoordinate=-5.52599999999999e-003
ZCoordinate=9.96477272727273e-003
RCoordinate=-2.18201293271677
TCoordinate=-1.19239958528248e-004
PositionName=Position 14

[StageMapPosition]
XCoordinate=-1.40625e-003
YCoordinate=-5.01925000000001e-003
ZCoordinate=9.96477272727273e-003
RCoordinate=-2.18201293271677
TCoordinate=-9.31942430672605e-005
PositionName=Position 13

[StageMapPosition]
XCoordinate=-1.387625e-003
YCoordinate=-4.68562500000001e-003
ZCoordinate=9.96477272727273e-003
RCoordinate=-2.18201293271677
TCoordinate=-9.31942430672605e-005
PositionName=Position 12
```

I just want to keep the data after XCoordinate and YCoordinate, so what I did is to read the file and split it according to the equal sign then the lign return as you can see here on my code :

```
   with open("E:/WOrk/PHD/SEM_images/NS65/Systematic_study/100_uM /NS_65_6_K_15_mM_100_uM_B4_66%_60_s/positionw.txt","r") as openfile:



    for line in openfile :


        s=line.split("=")


        for index,line in enumerate(s) :


            list=[index,line]
            list2=line.split("\n")
```

However I don't really understand what is hapenning in the line.split("\n") because i only get a list with the values after the = sign and i am not getting the XCoordinate string in the list.

Second thing is that then i want to say when XCoordinate is found in the list take the string after. I know i can make that using enumerate and the index. But when I am just trying to print true if XCoordinate is in there it doesn't print anything...

In the end I want something like that :

```
(values of XCoordinate)         (values of YCoordinate)
-1.37525e-003                    -5.52599999999999e-003
```

EDIT :

I changed my code and made a list of all the words in my file text :

```
with open("E:/WOrk/PHD/SEM_images/NS65/Systematic_study/100_uM/NS_65_6_K_15_mM_100_uM_B4_66%_60_s/positionw.txt","r") as openfile:


        separate=list()
        for line in openfile :


            s=line.split("=")


            for element in s :

                element2=element.split("\n")

                for value in element2: 


                    separate.append(value)

        for index,valeur in enumerate(separate) :

            chaine="XCoordinate"
            print(valeur)
            print("stop")
            if chaine in valeur :

                print("true")
```

Now I should get true everytime XCoordinate is showing up however it is not the case :/

Thanks for your help.

Mathais

Comment: show how should look the expected result

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the expected result

Comment: your expected output contains only first X/Y values, why?

Comment: Because i want to plot these values as a map

Comment: Anytime you're dealing with a specifically formatted file, your code will always be more sensible if you have an actual parser that transforms the file into some kind of in memory object. Then you can process the in memory objects using standard Python mechanisms (generators, comprehensions, `itertools`, potentially even numpy or other libraries). Is this a standardized file format? Can you find an existing parser if so? Can you use a more standard format (JSON, YAML, XML, etc.) if not?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this script will work for you

```
text=''
    regx =re.compile('((XCoordinate=[-]{0,1}[0-9]*.[0-9]*e-[0-9]*)\n(YCoordinate=[-]{0,1}[0-9]*.[0-9]*e-[0-9]*))')
    with open('test.txt', 'r+') as file:
        for line in file:
            text += line

    find = re.findall(regx,text)
    print ('findaa  ', find)
```

and the out will be

> [('XCoordinate=-1.37525e-003\nYCoordinate=-5.52599999999999e-003',
>   'XCoordinate=-1.37525e-003', 'YCoordinate=-5.52599999999999e-003'),
>   ('XCoordinate=-1.40625e-003\nYCoordinate=-5.01925000000001e-003',
>   'XCoordinate=-1.40625e-003', 'YCoordinate=-5.01925000000001e-003'),
>   ('XCoordinate=1.387625e-003\nYCoordinate=-4.68562500000001e-003',
>   'XCoordinate=1.387625e-003', 'YCoordinate=-4.68562500000001e-003')]